# Counter for tcolorbox

Tags: theorems, counters, tikz-styles, tcolorbox

I would like to create a boxes for

- theorem
- definition
- proposition

to looks like the following image ( but with **counter** for each box  ) :

[image]

I tired with `tcolorbox`

**Here's my code:**

```
%this is created by Mohcine 
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox{Box1}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!50!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}


\newtcolorbox{Box2}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white,
colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=black,
coltitle=white,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.15in},
                 boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white,},
title=#2,#1}

\newtcolorbox{Box3}[2][]{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white!20!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!30!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}

\newtcolorbox{Box4}[2][]{arc=0mm,
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!30!gray,
colframe=white!20!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!30!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{Box1}{Définition}
  Soit $X : \Omega \longrightarrow E$ une variable aléatoire. On appelle loi de $X$ l'application
    \[ P_{X} : X\left( \Omega \right)\to  [0,1],\quad x\mapsto \mathbb{P}\left( X=x\right)\]
\end{Box1}

\begin{Box2}{Proposition: Loi image}
 Soit $X : \Omega \longrightarrow E$  une variable aléatoire et $f : E \longrightarrow F$ . La loi de la variable aléatoire $Y=f\circ  X$
est donnée par
\[\forall y \in f\left(X\left(\Omega \right) \right),\quad \mathbb{P}\left(Y=y\right)=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}\left(\{y\} \right)}\mathbb{P}\left(X=x \right).  \]
\end{Box2}

\begin{Box4}{}
\begin{center}
{\Huge\textbf{Les méthodes à maitriser}}
\end{center}
\end{Box4}

\begin{Box3}{Méthode 26.1 : Savoir calculer la loi d'une variable aléatoire}
Il faut tout d'abord déterminer l'ensemble A des valeurs possibles de $X$, puis de calculer les
$\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)$, $x$ parcourant l'ensemble des valeurs prises par $X$. On représente généralement le résultat sous forme de tableau
\end{Box3}

\end{document}
```

Which produces :

[image]

Comment: why not using `\tcbnewtheorem` etc?

Comment: i don't know but could make the same style ?

Comment: I have removed the `mdframed` tag since that package is not used here

Comment: of course no problem, Good  texifying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest the usage of `\newtcbtheorem` -- it is configurable with options like any other `tcolorbox` environment, the `title` content is used from the 2nd argument. The 3rd. argument is meant for the label and can be left empty if not needed.

By using `auto counter` each theorem defines a 'personal' counter, with `number within=..` there's fine control on the numbering style.

The general syntax of a `\newtcbtheorem` definition is

```
\newtcbtheorem[init options]{theoremenvname}{Theorem Name}{options}{prefix}
```

where prefix is prepended to a possible label, i.e. if the prefix is `def` the label for foo would be `def:foo`, `\newtcbtheorem` uses a pre-defined label separator `:`, but this can be changed with the option `label separator=...`

The example for `method` environment shows how to specify the options.

Edit: [tcolorbox theorem numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415369/tcolorbox-theorem-numbering) is a related question.

```
%this is created by Mohcine 
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{definition}{Définition}{
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!50!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
boxed title style={colframe=black},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2mm},
}{def}


\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{proposition}{Proposition}{%
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white,
colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=black,
coltitle=white,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.15in},
                 boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white,},
}{prop}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{method}{Méthode}{%
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white!20!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!30!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
}{met}

\newtcolorbox{Box4}[2][]{arc=0mm,
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!30!gray,
colframe=white!20!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!30!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{}{}
  Soit $X : \Omega \longrightarrow E$ une variable aléatoire. On appelle loi de $X$ l'application
    \[ P_{X} : X\left( \Omega \right)\to  [0,1],\quad x\mapsto \mathbb{P}\left( X=x\right)\]
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}{Loi image}{}
 Soit $X : \Omega \longrightarrow E$  une variable aléatoire et $f : E \longrightarrow F$ . La loi de la variable aléatoire $Y=f\circ  X$
est donnée par
\[\forall y \in f\left(X\left(\Omega \right) \right),\quad \mathbb{P}\left(Y=y\right)=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}\left(\{y\} \right)}\mathbb{P}\left(X=x \right).  \]
\end{proposition}

\begin{Box4}{}
\begin{center}
{\Huge\textbf{Les méthodes à maitriser}}
\end{center}
\end{Box4}

\setcounter{chapter}{26}

\begin{method}[colbacktitle={yellow}]{Savoir calculer la loi d'une variable aléatoire}{}
Il faut tout d'abord déterminer l'ensemble A des valeurs possibles de $X$, puis de calculer les
$\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)$, $x$ parcourant l'ensemble des valeurs prises par $X$. On représente généralement le résultat sous forme de tableau
\end{method}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Educ: You're welcome. I've added the `boxed title style={colframe=black}` option to `definition` box -- it was missing (and is not shown in the screenshot)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have voted your answer and it is useful to regard even my question of my little book that I will present at the university. But Définition 1 borderless was better :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano: Well better or worse is opinion - based. Nobody is forced to do so. And actually, all is stated in the `tcolorbox` manual

Comment: @ChristianHupfer 
I hope you did not get angry.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution just using counters incremented before the title. I would advice you to prefix the counter value with your title setup (e.g. "Definition") per box so you do not have to type it every time.

```
%this is created by Mohcine 
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{mbo}
\newcounter{mbt}
\newcounter{mbth}

\newtcolorbox{Box1}[2][]{
            before title={\stepcounter{mbo}},
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white, fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!50!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2mm},
title={\thembo~#2},#1}


\newtcolorbox{Box2}[2][]{
            before title={\stepcounter{mbt}},
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white,
colframe=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=black,
coltitle=white,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.15in},
                 boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white,},
title={\thembt~#2},#1}

\newtcolorbox{Box3}[2][]{
            before title={\stepcounter{mbth}},
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=white!20!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!30!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
title={\thembth~#2},#1}

\newtcolorbox{Box4}[2][]{arc=0mm,
                lower separated=false,
                colback=white!30!gray,
colframe=white!20!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=white!30!gray,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{Box1}{Définition}
  Soit $X : \Omega \longrightarrow E$ une variable aléatoire. On appelle loi de $X$ l'application
    \[ P_{X} : X\left( \Omega \right)\to  [0,1],\quad x\mapsto \mathbb{P}\left( X=x\right)\]
\end{Box1}

\begin{Box2}{Proposition: Loi image}
 Soit $X : \Omega \longrightarrow E$  une variable aléatoire et $f : E \longrightarrow F$ . La loi de la variable aléatoire $Y=f\circ  X$
est donnée par
\[\forall y \in f\left(X\left(\Omega \right) \right),\quad \mathbb{P}\left(Y=y\right)=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}\left(\{y\} \right)}\mathbb{P}\left(X=x \right).  \]
\end{Box2}

\begin{Box4}{}
\begin{center}
{\Huge\textbf{Les méthodes à maitriser}}
\end{center}
\end{Box4}

\begin{Box3}{Méthode 26.1 : Savoir calculer la loi d'une variable aléatoire}
Il faut tout d'abord déterminer l'ensemble A des valeurs possibles de $X$, puis de calculer les
$\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)$, $x$ parcourant l'ensemble des valeurs prises par $X$. On représente généralement le résultat sous forme de tableau
\end{Box3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 thank you but i prefer solution of Christian Hupfer