# Enumerated tcolorbox title

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, tcolorbox

With my `tcolorbox`, I would to have an enumerate list as **Checkpoint** of the below figure.

[image]
Can anyone help me to create a numbered list as from picture in the picture inside `tcolorbox`?
I add a short MWE and thank you so much for your precious time and help. Regards. Sebastiano.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} %
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{classico}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{colback=teal!10,coltitle=black,colframe=gray!5,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1}

\newtcolorbox{mybox1}[1]{colback=yellow!40,coltitle=black,colframe=gray!5,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1, arc=0mm}
\begin{document}
\parindent 0cm

\chapter{Bla}

\section{One}

\begin{mybox}{}
\begin{equation}\label{Lorentz5}
t'=\frac{t-\dfrac{vx}{c^2}}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^{2}}}
\end{equation}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox1}{}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|\Delta \overline r| & =\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}\\
& =\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2}, \quad \text{\small (distanza spaziale)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{mybox1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362062/31729

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355503/30280

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not my preferred style and liking, but here is a solution with `\tcbsubtitle` and having an overlay for the subtitle.

The most important parameter in my point of view is the `left skip` value of the `subtitle style` in order to control the position of the red title box.

The `\CheckmarkBold` command is from `bbding` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} %
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{bbding}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{checkmarkbox}[1][]{
  colback=yellow!40,
  coltitle=black,
  colframe=gray!5,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  subtitle style={enhanced jigsaw,
    left skip=-0.5cm,
    boxsep=2pt,
    width=5cm,
    fontupper=\bfseries\Large,
    colback={red!60!white},
    colupper={red!60!black},
    boxrule=0pt,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    overlay={\node [left,outer sep=0.5em,green!60!black,draw,rectangle,line width=1.5pt] at (frame.west) {\CheckmarkBold};}},
  before upper={\tcbsubtitle{Checkpoint \thetcbcounter}%
  },
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\parindent0em

\chapter{Bla}

\section{One}


\begin{checkmarkbox}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|\Delta \overline r| & =\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}\\
& =\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2}, \quad \text{\small (distanza spaziale)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{checkmarkbox}


\begin{checkmarkbox}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|\Delta \overline r| & =\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}\\
& =\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2}, \quad \text{\small (distanza spaziale)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{checkmarkbox}

\begin{checkmarkbox}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|\Delta \overline r| & =\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}\\
& =\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2+(\Delta z)^2}, \quad \text{\small (distanza spaziale)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{checkmarkbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]