# tcolorbox theorem numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems, tcolorbox, newtheorem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling,multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{mytheo*}{}%
{colback=purple!5,colframe=blue!100!,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheo*}{title...}{}
text...
\end{mytheo*}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to make the theorem unnumbered, but I have not managed to figure out how to remove the number 1 and the colon that appear at the beginning of the theorem title. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding by the OP what `\newtcbtheorem` does actually:

`\newtcbtheorem{foo}{...}{...}{...}` will actually define both the numbered theorem - like enviroment `foo` **and** `foo*`, so `\newtcbtheorem{foo*}` will actually define `foo*` and `foo**`, leaving `foo*` being numbered however and `foo**` is the unnumbered version.

See page 340 of current `tcolorbox` manual for a description of this.

In addition, `hyperref` should be loaded as last package as almost always in 98% of all cases.

As a reply to the comment below by [Bryan-M-H](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/141384/bryan-m-h):

The unstarred version of the theorem has an additional mandatory argument that is meant for the label, see the changed example where the label is given as `{foo}`, which is extended to `th:foo` since the definition of the theorem has `th` as label prefix.

Related (but not duplicate) [Counter for tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355495/counter-for-tcolorbox)

Also related (no duplicate too): [Problem with tcolorbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423741/problem-with-tcolorbox-package)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling,multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbtheorem{mytheo}{My theorem}{colback=purple!5,colframe=blue!100!,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheo*}{}
  text...
\end{mytheo*}

See \ref{th:foo} 

\begin{mytheo}{Foo}{foo}
  text...
\end{mytheo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use the unstarred version of this in the body of the document, but found that the first letter of my theorem text was eaten up. [The word "text" came out as "ext" in the pink box.] What do I need to change?

    \begin{mytheo}{Fowler's Folly}
          text...
    \end{mytheo}

Comment: @BryanM-H: See my extended answer: You forgot the 2nd mandatory argument that is meant for the label of the unstarred environment. If you don't need a label, use `{}`