# Runaway Argument in \tcbtheorem

Tags: tcolorbox

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{defbox}{Definition}%
{   enhanced,
    arc=0mm,
    interior style={white},
    attach boxed title to top center= {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    fontupper=\itshape,
    colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={size=normal,colframe=white,boxrule=0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{defbox}{Theorem Name}
Description
\end{defbox}

\end{document}
```

Produces the following (cropped) output
[image: An almost correct output]

But my editor also says that there is a runaway argument. Likely for the same reason, there is an out of place D before the tcbtheorem.

My error log (I think?) says

```
 main.tex, line 19
Runaway argument?

{
! Paragraph ended before \tcb@theo@label was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.19 D
      escription
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> \tcb@theo@label {\par }
                                  {D}
l.19 D
      escription
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

While I partially understand what a runaway argument is, I haven't found it here, and I don't know what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `<prefix>` argument of `\newtcbtheorem` (see page 340 of the [manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)) and the `<label>` argument of `\begin{defbox}`.

With the `<prefix>` and `<label>` you can reference your theorem with `\ref{<prefix>:<label>}`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{defbox}{Definition}%
{   enhanced,
    arc=0mm,
    interior style={white},
    attach boxed title to top center= {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    fontupper=\itshape,
    colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={size=normal,colframe=white,boxrule=0pt}
}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{defbox}{Theorem Name}{mytheorem}
Description of theorem~\ref{th:mytheorem}.
\end{defbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: :-) I thinked that the answer was that of Christian of the black forest :-) Very good.

Comment: @Sebastiano Ooh :) He's the expert, I just searched the manual :)

Comment: LOL:-) In fact, I appreciate Christian very much as man and as LaTeX expert.

Comment: @Sebastiano: This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423741/problem-with-tcolorbox-package -- I just close-hammered it ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Who'd you hammer? You're so quiet and so funny. As you can see, I always compliment you even on the secret ahahah.