# Custom object that increments when inserted and can be referenced with labels

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, counters

I would like to create abbreviation such as CE1, CE2, etc. that as I introduce them through the document they automatically increase the counter. I would also be able to later reference them in the same way figures, tables, or equations are referenced.

Currently I have a macro to generate the new  abbreviations:

```
\newcommand{\ce}[1]{CE#1}
\newcounter{cec}
\setcounter{cec}{0}
\newcommand{\nce}{\stepcounter{cec}\ce{\thecec}}
```

In my document I would like to be able to do something like this (some of it can be adjusted or optimized with macros to my particular situation):

```
Here is a new \nce \label{ce:a} and here is another \nce \label{ce:b}.

Here I cite the CE\ref{ce:e}
```

The output of the reference should appear as CE1, CE2, and not include section numbers or anything else.

I would also like to use this code in creating custom environments like boxes with tcolorbox.

This seems like some basic latex function but I can't find a solution.

Comment: use `\refstepcounter` not `\stepcounter`

Comment: Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355495/counter-for-tcolorbox would be useful as well.